# What is the meaning of **taste** here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Intelligence is really a kind of taste: taste in ideas.
>
> —By Susan Sontag

Is *taste* used as noun?
What does the word actually express?

Comment: It's extrapolating from ***taste = preference*** ("Add sugar to taste") to ***refined / sophisticated** preference.* Compare [*He has good taste.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22He+has+good+taste%22)

Comment: [Here's](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/The_New_Consumer_Online/WLokCwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22He+has+good+taste%22&pg=PT63&printsec=frontcover) an excellent exposition on the precise implications and usage restrictions of ***taste*** in the relevant sense. You can have good taste in *clothes* or *handbags / fashion accessories*, but you can't really have good taste in something like vacuum cleaners or toothpaste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the noun *taste* is equivalent to refinement, good judgment in aesthetics, attitudes, etc.